# android Button :

Tags: java, android

Why we use Button in this way to initialize.

> **b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit1);**

And why we use (Button) before findViewById.

Thanks

Comment: First learn Java for casting the object.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `findViewById` is declared to returns a `View`. You need to downcast the return value to assign it to a `Button` variable. (I'm assuming from the code that you posted that `b1` is declared to be a `Button`.)

Note that if `bEdit1` does not correspond to a `Button` in the view hierarchy, then this will generate a `ClassCastException`. This should be something that you catch during development.

Comment: findviewbyId is from view class which is parent class. and Button is a sub class ? am i rite ?

Comment: @lizajohn - Yes. `findViewById` returns an object that is either a `View` or a subclass of `View`, depending on how the XML is declared (or how the view hierarchy was constructed). `Button` is a subclass of `View`.

Answer (score 1):

Views may have an integer id associated with them. These ids are typically assigned in the layout XML files, and are used to find specific views within the view tree. A common pattern is to:

```
Define a Button in the layout file and assign it a unique ID.

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/bEdit1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/my_button_text"/>
```

From the onCreate method of an Activity, find the Button

```
      Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit1);
```

View IDs need not be unique throughout the tree, but it is good practice to ensure that they are at least unique within the part of the tree you are searching.

Answer (score 0):

`(R.id.bEdit1)` is integer which is declare in `R.java` File so that we must Cast it in to Button to get Reference of it.

`R.java` file contains all variable declarations of application.

Answer (score 0):

While working with `Java` we do something like this

`JButton mbutt = new JButton("Click_Me");`

In above code we are `Creating` and `Assigning` an Object of Type `JButton` to the **Object Reference Variable** of type `JButton`.

While we work with `Android` we do something like this

`Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit1);`

Here **we have already created** the `Button` using the `XML`, and is now **referring to that** `Button object` using the above statement.

`(Button)` is an **explicit cast** done from `View` type to `Button` type. What we get from findViewById is a View, now we have to mention specifically what kinda view it is, here its Button.

Answer (score 0):

Signature of **findViewById** looks like

```
public final View findViewById (int id)
```

Which will, look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view.

```
final Button b1;
```

**findViewById(R.id.bEdit1);** Now it will looks for a view based on Id `bEdit1` and return you the view now your job is to cust it into a appropriate view.
that's way we do it as

`b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bEdit1);`